# Cómo presionar un input type button desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html

quería saber si hay alguna forma de presionar un input button desde javascript, porque quiero que cuando pase un tiempo predeterminado, toda la información introducida en mi formulario se guarde en mi bd, pero no consigo lo que quiero, he probado con este código:

```js
document.getElementById("boton_terminar").click();
```

```html
<form method="post">
<!----Mis inputs de texto---->
...
<!----Botón----->
<input type="submit" id="boton_terminar">
</form>
```

Lo único que hace es recargar la página, no envía nada, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Lo que deseas es enviar el formulario correcto?

Comment: Exacto, que después que pase un tiempo x, se envíe el formulario

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo son los campos que hay en el formulario?

Comment: Pues son de lo más simples, no te preocupes, ya lo conseguí, muchas gracias

Comment: <input type="text" name="respuesta10" placeholder="Escribe una respuesta..." class="input_answer">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `submit()` para enviar un formulario. Por ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").submit()
```

Donde "myForm" sería el id de tu formulario.

La documentación del método `submit()` la puedes revisar aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer para poder enviar los datos debes usar el metodo `submit()` al elemento **FORM** de la siguiente manera.

**Nota:** es necesario que le agreges un **id** para poder seleccionarlo, en este caso le agregue `id="form-datos"`. Cambia lo al que desees.

Para enviarlo luego de un tiempo `X` simplemente debes usar un `setTimeout`.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
document.getElementById('form-datos').submit();
}, tiempoEnMilisegundos);
```

```html
<form action="URL" method="post" id="form-datos">
<input type="submit" id="boton_terminar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes crear una rutina con `setInterval` para que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit()
    console.log('Se envian tus datos')
  }, 3000);


}
```

```html
<form method="post" id='myForm'>
  <!----Mis inputs de texto---->
  ...
  <!----Botón----->
  <input type="submit" id="boton_terminar">
</form>
```